# Custom Route to remove controller name from Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to remove the controller name from the URL in Areas

http://example.com/AreasName/my-page

I try this

```
 context.MapRoute("AreasName_default", "AreasName/{action}/{id}", new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

But it's getting an error:

> "The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which
> is required".

Answer (score 1):

Try to use attribute routing for area instead of calling the *MapRoute()*:

```
[RouteArea("AreasName")]   
[Route("{action}/{id}")]

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // url: /AreasName/about/id
    public ActionResult About(string id)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Message...";

        return View();
    }
    ...
}
```

To enabling attribute routing it is necassary to add a call to routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes() method with in RegisterRoutes() method of RouteConfig.cs file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // Enabling attribute routing. Recommend to put attribute routes in the route table before traditional routes.
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    // Additional calls
    routes.MapRoute(...)
}
```

Comment: Perfectly work! after adding this line to RouteConfig.cs :  "AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();"

Comment: @nawaz uddin: When I create a new project the Visual Studio template already includes the `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` as first line in the `Application_Start()` method.